# Punycode и кириллические домены для PHP – php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php

Функция `file_get_contents('')` выдает ошибку если

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: при попытки открыть адрес сайта которого состоит из кириллицы

После перевода урл в punycode тоже появляется ошибка! Пример урла `http://имя-сайта.рф`.

Как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Решите кардинально. 

**Не работайте** с кириллическими доменами (почтовыми адресами и т.п.) вообще. Просто не пишите такой софт и вскоре проблема исчезнет.

Comment: иногда от этого никуда не деться. А не пробовали искать проблему в кодировке? Скорее всего виновата кодировка файла с кодом php

Comment: еще есть вариант воспользоваться этим http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [php-punycode](https://github.com/true/php-punycode).

```
use TrueBV\Punycode; 

$url        = 'http://домены.рф/партнерская-программа';
$urlDetails = parse_url($url); 

$punycode = new Punycode();
$domain   = $punycode->encode($urlDetails['host']);

$content  = file_get_contents($urlDetails['scheme']. '://' . $domain . $urlDetails['path']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Punycode используйте для конвертации названия домена.

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.